# Validation between two tables having conversion logic between them

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables for which comparison needs to be performed.

Hundreds of thousands of data might be present so manual validation is not possible.

Validation is done with a tool which compares the corresponding columns of both tables for each primary key (ID)

Column names - ID(primary key), TYPE ( values allowed P or O ), Date of birth, foundation date

P means person & O means organization
If type = P, then dob value will be present and foundation date will be null
If type = O, then dob will be null and foundation date value will be present

Example

```
Table 1:
(1,P,1972-08-09,null)
(2,O,null,1994-05-04)
(3,P,1995-08-09,null)
(4,O,null,1990-07-06)

Table 2:

(1,P,1972-08-09,null)
(2,O,null,1994-05-06)
(3,P,1995-07-19,null)
(4,O,null,1990-07-06)
```

For the above example, record number 2 & 3 are mismatch and should be reported.

Now, there exists a conversion logic between these two tables due to which few party records are converted to organisation and vice versa.

In the below example, record 1 is converted from P to O :

```
Table 1:
(1,P,1972-08-09,null)
(2,O,null,1994-05-04)
(3,P,1995-08-09,null)
(4,O,null,1990-07-06)

Table 2:
(1,O,null,1972-08-09)
(2,O,null,1994-05-04)
(3,P,1995-08-09,null)
(4,O,null,1990-07-06)
```

Due to this convertion the value which was stored in dob is stored in foundation date and dob is set as null and vice versa.

Now when we will compare these tables with the tool that we have then it will show record 1 as mismatch.

But if we run 2 individual queries for the tables just for record 1 and verify the data manually we can say that this is not an issue.

Now, imagine this situation for lakhs of data where there are thousands of mismatch.

Remember these mismatches can be genuine as seen in example 1 or just due to convertion logic as seen in case 2.

The first type can be identified by running the tool twice, once for only P and the other time for only O individually.

But for the second type we use sampling technique and check manually for 5-6 data ( even though there are thousands or hundreds of thousands of mismatch) and if those 5-6 data are populated correctly we assume all these are non issue

Can this entire validation be implemented in a better manner?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Just coalesce the 2 date fields in each record and then compare the coalesced values between tables when you join them on the PK